# Why hints are not visible when a cursor is over them?

Tags: c#, button, devexpress, tooltip

My question concerns visibility of hints in an application using DevExpress (C#) controls. The application has a panel on which there are several controls, and only one appears at a given moment. A user can choose which control should appear by switching among them. The controls have their bar with several buttons (different buttons for each type of control).

The problem is that the hints on the buttons sometimes do not appear when the mouse cursor is over them. They appear after opening the application, but when the user switches to a control of the same type, the hints are not visible. When the user switches to a control of another type, the hints can appear, but not always (I could not find the rule). But always, when the user goes to a window of another application and returns, the hints appear. The property `ShowScreenTipsInToolbars` for the bar manager has the value `true` during execution of the program.

Do you know the cause of this strange behavior? And what to do to make the hints always visible when a mouse cursor is over the buttons? I am not the author of the application (I was asked if it is possible to solve the problem) and I cannot give too many technical details.

Answer (score 0):

If a control does not have focus, then none of the children of that control are aware that the mouse is hovering over them. Thus you don't get tool-tips. This will be the case until focus passes to the control (usually with a left-click within the control's bounds).

Without seeing any code, my best guess is that whatever code is responsible for switching the control visibility is not also guaranteeing that the visible control has focus. The documentation for [Control.Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) might help here (note that there are exceptions to the `Control.Focus()` method's ability to set the focus.)